# Why can we pass an lvalue as the paramter for std::move?

Tags: c++

I understand that `std::move()` could accept either an lvalue or an rvalue as the parameter, i.e., `std::move(5)` or `i = 5; std::move(i)` are both valid. However, on cppreference.com, the official function signature for `std::move()` is:

[image: std::move function signature]

And the parameter for `std::move()` seems to be an rvalue. I was wondering, why can we still pass an lvalue as the parameter when we use `std::move()`?

Comment: `T && t` is a forwarding reference and can match an lvalue or an rvalue see  [Forwarding references](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references)

Comment: Calling `std::move` on a rvalue isn't really useful. The whole point of `std::move` is to make a rvalue (xvalue) from a lvalue.